# Python renaming files being weird

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function:

```
def rename(path):
    """ Renames all the files to be cropped-%d.xxx """
    count = 0
    for thing in os.listdir(path):
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(thing)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, thing), os.path.join(path, sys.argv[1]+".cropped{0}".format(count)+ext))
        count += 1
```

This works, but if I run it on a directory which I have already run it on, it seems to delete half of the files its renaming. Why would this happen?

Comment: Where in your code do you take precautions that the directory doesn't already contain a file with the name you are renaming to?

Comment: Perhaps you are renaming on top of existing files. (This is not an error; the old file will simply be deleted.)

Comment: ah yes that would be it. now how to do a neat check. i can do an if in and check if the name exists i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to see what's happening if you print out the renaming you're doing:

```
def rename(path):
    """ Renames all the files to be cropped-%d.xxx """
    count = 0 
    for thing in os.listdir(path):
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(thing)
        old = os.path.join(path, thing)
        new = os.path.join(path, sys.argv[1] + ".cropped{0}".format(count) + ext)
        print("rename from {} to {}".format(old, new))
        os.rename(old, new)
        count += 1
```

Here's sample output running twice:

```
dan@dandesk:~$ python ok.py b
rename from test/4.txt to test/b.cropped0.txt
rename from test/2.txt to test/b.cropped1.txt
rename from test/5.txt to test/b.cropped2.txt
rename from test/7.txt to test/b.cropped3.txt
rename from test/1.txt to test/b.cropped4.txt
rename from test/3.txt to test/b.cropped5.txt
rename from test/6.txt to test/b.cropped6.txt
dan@dandesk:~$ python ok.py b
rename from test/b.cropped3.txt to test/b.cropped0.txt
rename from test/b.cropped4.txt to test/b.cropped1.txt
rename from test/b.cropped2.txt to test/b.cropped2.txt
rename from test/b.cropped5.txt to test/b.cropped3.txt
rename from test/b.cropped1.txt to test/b.cropped4.txt
rename from test/b.cropped0.txt to test/b.cropped5.txt
rename from test/b.cropped6.txt to test/b.cropped6.txt
```

And now here's the test directory contents:

```
dan@dandesk:~$ ls -1 test
b.cropped2.txt
b.cropped3.txt
b.cropped4.txt
b.cropped5.txt
b.cropped6.txt
```

As you can see, `b.cropped1.txt` and `b.cropped0.txt` have disappeared. The output above reveals why:

```
rename from test/b.cropped3.txt to test/b.cropped0.txt
rename from test/b.cropped4.txt to test/b.cropped1.txt
...
rename from test/b.cropped1.txt to test/b.cropped4.txt
rename from test/b.cropped0.txt to test/b.cropped5.txt
```

We rename two files to the missing names, and then rename them *again* later, which means we lose whatever was in `b.cropped4.txt` and `b.cropped5.txt`.

You can avoid this by making sure the new name you're going to use doesn't already exist, and if it does, increment `count` until you get a file that doesn't exist:

```
def rename(path):
    """ Renames all the files to be cropped-%d.xxx """
    count = 0
    for thing in os.listdir(path):
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(thing)
        old = os.path.join(path, thing)
        while True:
            new = os.path.join(path, sys.argv[1] + ".cropped{0}".format(count) + ext)
            if not os.path.exists(new):
                break
            count += 1
        print("rename from {} to {}".format(old, new))
        os.rename(old, new)
        count += 1
```

Output:

```
dan@dandesk:~$ python ok.py b
rename from test/4.txt to test/b.cropped0.txt
rename from test/2.txt to test/b.cropped1.txt
rename from test/5.txt to test/b.cropped2.txt
rename from test/1.txt to test/b.cropped3.txt
rename from test/3.txt to test/b.cropped4.txt
rename from test/6.txt to test/b.cropped5.txt
dan@dandesk:~$ python ok.py b
rename from test/b.cropped3.txt to test/b.cropped6.txt
rename from test/b.cropped4.txt to test/b.cropped7.txt
rename from test/b.cropped2.txt to test/b.cropped8.txt
rename from test/b.cropped5.txt to test/b.cropped9.txt
rename from test/b.cropped1.txt to test/b.cropped10.txt
rename from test/b.cropped0.txt to test/b.cropped11.txt
```

Comment: +1 for seriously thorough answer, even though it basically says what I said, after I said it ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would happen when a file with the new name already exists, so you are replacing an existing file with a renamed one, losing the original in the process.